# Output the first letter of each string in an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, char, output

This is for my homework assignment so I don't want any code answers just an explanation on how best to proceed.

I have set up a program that takes user input and adds them to an array list.

I can output the list by using System.out.println(list); but I need to print only the first character of each word.

How should I go about doing this?

Cheers...

Comment: use a *for each loop* and `charAt()` method of String class.

Comment: In case you're wondering about the mass of down-votes - it's because you've demonstrated a staggeringly small amount of effort and prior research.

Comment: what you have tried till now?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would be to loop over every `String` in your `List`, and for each of these take the first character (Look at [the docs for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for this) and then print it in your usual way (I'd guess at `System.out.println()`).

Answer (score 0):

I get the -1, but anyways... Here's what you will have to learn from your assignment:

1.) Iterate (or loop) through every String in your list.

2.) String manipulation: Only get the first character of your string by adressing it's index (position) in the string

For every string in your list,  print out the first letter of the string you currently have in your "hands" while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

@sunrize920 already gave you the answer...

I'll try to give you the way to find it.

There are rather good documentation of the Java API on Oracle home page
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html

from the API page you can find what methods are available for the classes you use.
E.g.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

That should get you to the answer by yourself.

If you are starting to learn programming you might also want to establish a few good habits early...

Have a look at JavaDOC and Junit.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit

Answer (score -1):

```
for(String s: list){
    System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
}
```

Prints the character at the zeroth index of the string for each String `s` in the list

Comment: @Duncan yeah because he was afraid people wouldn't help him on a homework question if they thought he was just asking for code...duh

Comment: Well, some people want to learn without being spoon fed. What does posting the code gain in either case?